# Random sampling in fortran

Tags: fortran

I have the following data

```
X     Y    INFTIME
1     1     0
1     2     4
1     3     4
1     4     3
2     1     3
2     2     1
2     3     3
2     4     4
3     1     2
3     2     2
3     3     0
3     4     2
4     1     4
4     2     3
4     3     3
4     4     0
```

X and Y represent he X and Y components in the square grid of 4 by 4. 
Here I want to sample randomly 10% from the population which are infected i.e, whose INFTIME is non zero. I did not get any idea of coding so could not start it. 
Any suggestions and idea will be great for me.
Thanks

EDIT:

```
DO T = 1,10
   DO i = 1, 625

      IF(INFTIME(i)/=0 .AND. INFTIME(i) .LE. T)THEN
         CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(u(i))
         u(i) = 1+aint(u(i)*25)
          CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(v(i))
         v(i) = 1+aint(v(i)*25)
          CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(w(i))
         w(i) = 1+aint(w(i)*10)
      ENDIF
   ENDDO
ENDDO


do p = 1,625
  WRITE(*,*) u(p),v(p),w(p)
 enddo
```

This is my code what I tried but it only gives the random numbers, not the connection to the data. I used the data of 25 by 25 grids i.e, 625 individuals and time of infection 1 to 10

Comment: I could not start. I only know that we can sample randomly for one dimensional array bu using the uniform random number generation, but this case is different so I did not get any idea how to start.

Comment: Since you have three 1D arrays (one for X, one for Y and one for INFTIME) then randomly select a row and throw it away if INFTIME==0. Stop when you reach 10% of samples.

Comment: Thanks ja72, I also thought that one but when i select randomly from different column, they may not lie in the same row. Since the coordinate(X,Y) is an individual, they should be from the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow what ja72 said. You have three 1D arrays of the same size (16). All you need to do is pick a number between 1 and 16, check to see if INFTIME is zero and accept the value as needed, then repeat until you've taken 10% of the samples (which would be 1.6 values, so I presume you'd just take 2? Or do you have more data than this 4x4 you presented?)

**Edit** You need to call the random number generator *before* the `if` statement:

```
    do t=1,10
      do i=1,625
          ind = 1+int(624*rand(seed))
          if(inftime(ind).neq.0 .and. inftime(ind).le.t) then
             stuff
          endif
       enddo
    enddo
```

The call `ind=1+int(625*rand(seed))` will pick a random integer between 1 (when `rand(seed)=0`) and 625 (when `rand(seed)=1`). Then you can do what you need if the `if` statement is satisfied.

EDIT: program  epimatrix

```
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER ::l, i,T,K
REAL, DIMENSION(1:625):: X,y,inftime
INTEGER::seed,my_cnt
INTEGER,DIMENSION(8) :: time1
CALL DATE_AND_TIME(values=time1)
seed = 1000*time1(7)+time1(8)
call srand(seed)

OPEN(10, FILE = 'epidemicSIR.txt', FORM = 'FORMATTED')
DO l = 1,625
   READ(10,*,END = 200) X(l), Y(l), INFTIME(l)
  ! WRITE(*,*) X(l),Y(l), INFTIME(l)
  ! if you know how it was formatted, you should use
  ! read(10,20) X(l), Y(l), INFTIME(l)
  ! where 20 is the format
ENDDO
200 CONTINUE
CLOSE(10)

DO T = 1,10
   my_cnt=0
   write(*,*) "T=",T
   DO while (my_cnt.le.63)
      K = 1+int(624*rand())
      IF(INFTIME(K)/=0 .AND. INFTIME(K) .LE. T)THEN
         write(*,*) X(k),Y(k),INFTIME(k)
         my_cnt=my_cnt+1
      ENDIF
   enddo
   write(*,*) " "
ENDDO

end program
```

**EDIT 2**
I've adjusted the program to fix some of the issues. I've tried keeping my edits in lowercase so that you can see the difference. The `do-while` loop allows the code to continue running until the condition `my_cnt.le.63` has been met (which means you have 63 lines of X, Y, inftime *per T*). I've added a line to output T and another line to add a space so that the data might be more clear when looking at the output.

This should take care of all the issues you've been running into. If not, I'll keep checking this page.

Comment: Actually, the `do i=1,625` should be a `do-while` loop with the conditional that some counter in the `if`-statement should be less than 10% of 625 (62 or 63, depending how you round).

Comment: (1) My assumption is that 'i' is not an integer, which it should be.  (2) I should not have included `seed` in the call `ind=1+int(624*rand(seed))`, it should read `ind=1+int(624*rand())`. My mistake :( (3) Not sure why it would affect the value of `T`, as that has not been incremented anywhere.

Comment: Scratch answer (3) above. The way the code is written, it looks like only INFTIME(k)=1 will be displayed for T=1, then INFTIME(k)=1,2 will be displayed for T=2, and so on. Is there a reason for this? You also want to turn `do i=1,63` into a `do-while` loop with a counter that increments by 1 (inside the `if` statement) and exits the loop when the counter is equal to 63.

Comment: The `my_cnt.le.63` condition of the `do-while` loop takes care of that 10% and the `write(*,*) X(k), Y(k), INFTIME(K)` line inside the `if` statement outputs the value of INFTIME(K) (and the position on the x-y grid) so your sample is taken care of. Do you need to do any math on the INFTIME? If so, that can easily be done inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks Kyle for the explanation. Actually I need to sample 10% of the population from each time point. For example if there are 100 individuals  infected at time T = 4, then I need to sample 10 of them at time T = 4 and so on. The code what we developed only gives 63 lines for each T.